# Bake the animation of a rig following another rig

Tags: animation, rigging, baking

I have a Kinect Rig imported into Blender.

My character is moving thanks to another rig (lets name it the Character's Rig) which is following the Kinect rig.

I cleaned up the animation of the Kinect rig, and made some adjustments in pose mode to the Character's rig (mainly foot rotation).

Everything is good, except that sometimes in the viewport, and everytime when rendering, some of the adjustment are not calculated (foot rotation correction for example).

**Is there a typical workflow to bake the animation of my Character's Rig, so that I can delete the Kinect rig, making my Character's Rig absolutely independant ? What are the different ways to achieve this ?** Especially if I need to use the NLA Editor after this.

I know there's the Pose > Bake Action solution in Pose Mode, but is it really what I need ?

Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `Pose Mode` and select all bones of your character's rig.
Select `Pose`->`Animation`->`Bake Action` like below:

[image: path to bake action]

then select `Only Selected Bones` + `Visual Keying` + `Clear Constrains` + `Overwrite Current Action`

[image: bake action options]

Comment: ok so if I understand you, proceeding this way will bake ALL the animation data? I mean, will it allow to bake both the movements inherited from the Kinect rig, and also the correction movements on the character's rig ? (that was the sense of my question in my initial post when I said "is it really what I need ?"). Thanks for your answer btw :)

Comment: And, just to understand how it works, does it mean that, in the end, this "Bake Action" is baking the rig's **movement** at every frame, no matter the source of those movements ? (i.e regardless of weither the keyframes at the source of the animation comes from the kinect or the character's rig). Like it was visually scanning every selected bones movements and bake it ? If it works that way, this is absolutely powerfull. In any case I apologize, I may not be clear (i'm french sry) but I don't really understand how this "Bake action" option works :)

Comment: This gives you keys in all frames you determine. Following another rig in a sense that you use *any* kind of constraints, drivers, animation nodes or so is included but I think you should remove drivers manually after the process. I suggest you to test different options if you didn't get the desired result.(have that in mind that the process is **undoable**)

Comment: (Sry for the delay, I had to take a break for my project this past week !) Thanks for your answers, this is pretty clear now !