# It is posible to obtain a armature from a Rig?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

I just installed rokoko. I am trying to retarget a Rig which armature has been already deleted but it seems that Rokoko only uses armature as a source.

Is there a way to convert the rig that I have to an Armature?[image]

Comment: I did something very similar with copy rotation /location.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a `copy transforms` constraint on each of your bones and set the rigged armature's bones as target. then `bake` the animation by selecting `clear constraints`.
for baking see [baking with reference question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/203417/bake-the-animation-of-a-rig-following-another-rig/203426#203426)

Comment: you can also do the process by code.